# Mocking a global object when unit testing function with jasmine

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine

I need to write tests for legacy JavaScript script which runs from `node.js`. It has a global object which is initialised in one function and then accessed from another. I mean `script.js` looks like:

```
var object;

function first() {
    object = Initialise.object();
    ...
}

function second() {
    object.doSomething();
    ...
}
```

I need to write a unit test for the `second()` function. We are using a jasmine test framework and I am struggling to create a mock (stub) for the `object`. It is because I don't know how can I access it from `script-spec.js`. I have tried

```
var script = require("../src/script.js");
var testObject = script.object;
```

but `testObject` is `undefined`.

My knowledge of `JavaScript` is limited which doesn't help me as well (I have `Java` background).

How can I test `second()` function? I understand that I might need to refactor/redesign `script.js` which I am OK with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rewrite the code to be more functional:

```
function first() {
    return Initialise.object();
}

function second(object) {
    object.doSomething();
    ...
}
```

Then later when the code is used:

```
var object = first()
second(object)
```

Then mocking becomes pretty trivial, because you can control what gets passed as an argument to `second` in the test.

Check out [Avoid Side Effects in the Clean Code Javascript repo](https://github.com/ryanmcdermott/clean-code-javascript#avoid-side-effects-part-1) for some more info about this.

Answer (score 1):

It would be easier if it was a global variable, you could just do a `global.object = mockObject`.  What it really is a module level variable, modules are really just functions.  The only way to reassign `object` is from a function defined inside script.js such as

```
function injectMockObject (mockObject) {
  object = mockObject;
}
```

which you would need to add to script.js